# Intercept URL containing values or not

Tags: objective-c, url

I need to intercept a URL and go outside the `WebView` if the URL contains `MAPS` or `DOCUMENTS` constants. I must also go outside if `url` does not contain the value of `DOMAIN` and `LOGIN_SALES_FORCE`.

This is working nice, but seems ugly for me. Any ideas?

```
if ([request.URL.absoluteString rangeOfString:MAPS      ].location != NSNotFound ||
    [request.URL.absoluteString rangeOfString:DOCUMENTS ].location != NSNotFound)
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:request.URL.absoluteString];
    return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
} else if ([request.URL.absoluteString rangeOfString:DOMINIO           ].location == NSNotFound &&
           [request.URL.absoluteString rangeOfString:LOGIN_SALES_FORCE ].location == NSNotFound) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:request.URL.absoluteString];
    return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know Objective-C. The proposed changes are quite basic, though, and should give the same result as your original code.

## Intermediate variables

To shorten your expressions, you may want to use an intermediate variable:

```
NSString *absUrl = request.URL.absoluteString;
```

Then, you can group your conditions using boolean operators.

## Boolean logic

```
if (   [absUrl rangeOfString:MAPS].location != NSNotFound 
    || [absUrl rangeOfString:DOCUMENTS].location != NSNotFound
    || (    [absUrl rangeOfString:DOMINIO].location == NSNotFound
         && [absUrl rangeOfString:LOGIN_SALES_FORCE].location == NSNotFound))
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:request.URL.absoluteString];
    return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

## Remarks

Reading this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/index.html), I find it strange that you are converting `request.URL` to `url` using `URLWithString`. I may be wrong, but you could use `absoluteUrl` to achieve the same effect.